# Fire mouseenter / mouseleave event with drag en drop in edge animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to make a demo with visual feedback. A draggable element has to be dropped on a droppable element.
This works perfectly with the inserted jquery and jquery-ui script.

My question:

I want to add a visual feedback by adding a mouseenter and mouseleave on this object (dragenter or dragover isn't supported within edge so thats no option).
Because i'm dragging an image the droppable element doesn't fire the mouse events since there is simply a image inbetween them.

How can I make the droppable object see the mouse and still work when dropped?

```
sym.$("pdf_file").draggable({
  opacity: 0.40,
  revert: "invalid",
});


sym.$("droppable_object_01").droppable({
  accept: sym.$("pdf_file"),
  drop: function(){
  sym.play('start_drag_pdf_01');
  }
});

sym.play('mouse_enter').css({
  'opacity': 0.99,
});

sym.play('mouse_leave').css({
  'opacity': 0.00
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery-ui's draggables have the `over` and `out` events that you can use:

```
sym.$("droppable_object_01").droppable({
    over: function() {
        // Run any code when the draggable is dragged over the droppable
    },
    out: function() {
        // Run any code when the draggable is dragged out of the droppable
    }
});
```

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/5jtoawp8/

More information [in the docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over).

Comment: Thank you! I added the opacity that I wanted to give as feedback to the user in the JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5jtoawp8/3/

Answer (score -2):

```
 <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#dvRestrictedArea").mouseenter(function () {
            alert("Mouce Enter into Restricted Area");
        });
        $("#dvRestrictedArea").mouseleave(function () {
            alert("Mouce leave from Restricted Area");
        });
    });

</script>
```

[image: Click to see Out Put Screen]

[image: Code Section]

Thanks... :)

Comment: Your code will trigger the `alert()` regardless the drag&drop of the image inside the droppable element.